# jquery regional datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an issue in making datepicker regional.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var culture= $("#culture").val();

        $("#dob").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            yearRange: '-90:-15',
            defaultDate: '-90y'
        });
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[""]);       //need en-In as default region
       // $("#dob").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["en"]);
        $("#dob").datepicker("option",
          $.datepicker.regional[culture]);
        });
});
</script>
```

**Issue** :dob textbox not displaying value in edit mode. **WHY??<**br/>
If i remove all below lines of code that i used for making datepicker regional then all everything works fine for me.

Comment: Can you present this in a jsfiddle page so that we can look at it 'live'.

Comment: What is in your variable culture? What string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var abc = $("#culture").val();


        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);//this will set default lacale to ENGLISH
        $("#dob").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            yearRange: '-90:-15',
            defaultDate: '-90y'
        });
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[culture]); //This will set default locale to current "culture"
        });
});

</script>
```

This is not the correct way i think, just try it and let me know if it works?

Comment: Working kannas. but as u said this is not the correct way to do it. can you please elaborate it for me, because i am new on it thats why i am bit curious .

Comment: @djCool i have no prior experience with Localization and regional  datepicker , sorry cant help you in that context.